# Does PDO's rowCount() really returns 0 when run more than once for UPDATE query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-update

`UPDATE table SET foo = 'bar' WHERE id = 1`

If you run this once, `PDOStatement::rowCount()` returns `1`, but if you run it again (more than once), the succeeding run returns `0`.

I was wondering if this is really the expected behavior? Isn't it suppose to always return `1` since you are basically updating/affecting the same row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rowCount()` reports on the number of rows *actually modified* by an `UPDATE` statement. If you call the same `UPDATE` statement twice, the second time there will not be any rows requiring modification (since they changed the first time).  So the number of affected rows actually is 0 the second time.

If you ran the same thing in the console, you would see something like the following, indicating that although a row met your criteria, its column values already were what you attempted to change them to, and hence they remain unchanged.

```
Rows matched: 1 Changed: 0 Warnings: 0
```